# Residues of $\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{(z+1)(z+2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to find the residue at $z= -1$ and $z=-2$ of the following function:

$$f(z) =  \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{(z+1)(z+2)}$$

I now that $f(z)$ has a double pole at $z=-1$ because $\sin(-\pi) = 0 $. Now for a double pole the residue should be:
$$\lim\limits_{z \to -1} \frac{d}{dz} \frac{(z+1) \pi \cot(\pi z)}{z+2}$$

However evaluating the differentiation of that term can be quite annoying especially if you don't remember the "formula" for $\cot(z)$. Is there a more simple to evaluate this?

I know that the answer should be $-1$ (checked with Maple)

Comment: The formula for $\frac {d}{dz} \cot z = -\csc^2 z$ and can be derived in about 30 seconds.  You could say $u = z+1, \cot \pi z = \cot (\pi u - \pi) = \cot (\pi u) $  then use Taylor series about $u = 0$

Comment: so do you recommend just differentiate and then check the limit? Because when you differentiate you get: ${\frac {\cos \left( \pi\,z \right) \sin \left( \pi\,z \right) -\pi\,
 \left( z+2 \right)  \left( z+1 \right) }{ \left( \sin \left( \pi\,z
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( z+2 \right) ^{2}}}$ and then to find the limit you would have to differentiate again for the Hopital rule.

Answer (score 1):

A series expansion is probably the quickest way here. An [important sum identity for cotangent](https://people.reed.edu/%7Ejerry/311/cotan.pdf) is:
$$
\pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} +2z \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^2-n^2} = \frac{1}{z}+\frac{2z}{z^2-1} +\frac{2z}{z^2-4}+\frac{2z}{z^2-9}+\cdots
$$Let $f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{(z+1)(z+2)}$. Each singularity is a double pole, so to compute the residues we have
$$
\text{Res}(f(z);z=-1) = \lim_{z\to -1} \frac{2z}{(z^2-1)(z+1)(z+2)}\cdot \frac{(z+1)^2}{1!} = \lim_{z\to -1}\frac{2z}{(z-1)(z+2)}=-1
$$The residue at $z=-2$ is computed similarly and is found to be $-1$ as well.